# SQL - IDENTITY Increment for starting numbers for specific race

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a database for races and I have a problem.

I would like to auto increment starting numbers in the link table `Race_has_Racers.` The numbers should start incrementation from 1 to N.

Is it possible to increment separately for a specific race?

**For example**, if I have a race with `ID=1` and a racer with `ID=21 join` so his starting number is 1, then a racer with `ID=15` join and his starting number is `2`.

Now I create a race with `ID=2` and the racer with `ID=15` join this race and his number is `1`, then a racer with `ID=7` joins the race with `ID=1` so his starting number will be `3`.

> It is possible to make this automatic or should I add starting numbers
> before the race begins?

Comment: `IDENTITY` is per table. If you want to reset the ID per "race" you would be better off using `ROW_NUMBER` and a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Race` table, a `Racer` table and that your `Race_has_Racers` table is in the following format:

```
CREATE TABLE Race_has_Racers
(
    RaceID INT,
    RacerID INT,
    JoinDateTime DATETIME
)
```

Then you could write a query as follows to achieve your desired result:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RaceId ORDER BY JoinDateTime),
       RacerId,
       RaceId
FROM   Race_has_Racers
```

[Identity's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) purpose is to generate incrementing values in a table, usually used to autoincrement a Primary Key